# I can't find Xpath on this website or maybe wrong syntax

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, google-sheets-formula, screen-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** data from this url https://drive.getbigger.io/#/stores, however I didn't find the Xpath of the text I want to export, which are the producer's offer.

Firstly I try the **importxml** function in Google sheet:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"/html/body/flt-ruler-host/div[23]/p")
```

and it gave me N/A error "the imported content is empty"

so I try to **scrape** this website with add-ons and Parsehub, and it gave me every time a .csv file where i can't find the data I want to export.

Also I can't find the right Xpath for the data I would like to scrape, when I use the inspection tool, the data isn't in the `<body>` part.

However the Xpath I use in my importXML function is some code I find in the `<body>` part and which is close of the text I'd like to extract (the producer's offer).

It seems that the Xpath I am looking for is linked in the `<head>` part with some JavaScript code, also when I hover the page with the selection tool in order to scrape the data it select the whole page, maybe because there is a "scroll `<div>`".

So I wonder if the website use some kind of protection against scraping or other.

Please guys tell me if :

- I could find the right Xpath in order to **scrape** with the importXML function?
- Should I extract the data with a python script?
- if the website block my attempts, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to scrape anything with `IMPORTXML` formula since the website uses dynamic rendering (javascript).

So yes, Python+Selenium (or other combinations) could do the job. The website won't block you if you follow some rules (switch user-agent, add pauses between requests).

You would probably need these XPath :

Product description :

```
//p[1][string-length(text())>5][parent::flt-dom-canvas]
```

Product price :

```
//p[3][contains(text(),"€") and not (contains(text(),","))][parent::flt-dom-canvas]
```

However, I think the most elegant way to get the data is probably to use the [API](https://api.ledrivelocal.fr/) the website relies upon. With GoogleSheets and a custom [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/ae64c908b82cc8cf8840e176930ad937883fbe37/ImportJSON.gs) script, you can obtain something like this (result for "fromage" as query) :

[image: Drive]

It won't work out of the box, you'll have to modify some parts of the script since it won't load a JSON (called with POST) which needs headers in the request. In a nutshell, you need to construct the payload part, add headers to the request ("Bearer XXXXX"), and add a parameter to a function to retrieve the results.

All this depends on your objective and your expected output.

EDIT : For references (constructing the payload, adding parameters) you can read :

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params

Look also the networktab of your browser developper tools in order to find : the url of the API and the correct parameters to send.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I didn't even know i could use the api, however i didn't understand this part :<br/> "It won't work out of the box, you'll have to modify some parts of the script since it won't load a JSON (called with POST) which needs headers in the request. In a nutshell, you need to construct the payload part, add headers to the request ("Bearer XXXXX"), and add a parameter to a function to retrieve the results." @E.Wiest

Comment: Could you explain to me in french

Comment: If i understand you mean that :

Comment: 1) i need to construct the payload (modify the script) 2) to add headers ("/path") 3) to add parameter ("fromage" ?)

Comment: Yes, I suppose I can post this somewhere.  https://hebdo.framapad.org/p/r.be561417eb3803876e5f51503e5b3494 I think that's a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you tag:E.Wiest ! It works.

However besides producer's and product's name, 
i'd like to extract other data like for example : the company's name, adress/location, etc...

would it be possible to export everything, then sort data from sheets ?

how to find the path to data (ex:/data/firstName) ? 

I use the inspection tool and go to the Network section,
i find the contentType but can't find the Header 

Authorization : 'Bearer WXlvsZ5Xs02icuFiO81v3UNAY16xPPXv'

and the right api url either with my browser developper tools

Comment: If i want to reproduce this process on other websites which have an api (when it's not documented), 
the only thing i have to do in my script is to find the api's url using browser development tools then,
build the payload part by modify/add the research parameters in formData, 
then add, in options part, (method, contentType, headers) that i am supposed to find with browser development tools ?

Comment: I'm a bit late. Some clues here : https://hebdo.framapad.org/p/9gu4-i4cj1qrpfe?lang=fr

Comment: Hello, thank you for your return. Indeed following your explanations I managed to find using the developer tools the header, the URL and the method.

However, I cannot extract the raw data. I tried :

1. Not to specify the data path
2. I tried with the URL "secured / products"
3. I tried modifying the script, changing the method to GET
4. I tried with the original script (github)

None of them work.

Is this due to the fact that I have to delete the payload? Or maybe it is my URL that is wrong (I did not try to put the search terms in the URL).